# OP_EQUAL not working properly

Tags: script, hash, utxo, output, transaction-input

I went to https://siminchen.github.io/bitcoinIDE/build/editor.html to try some bitcoin scripting and I wrote this script:

```
<1PUzZ61FSVTn12CafJC85Vy1ts3BoFcXdU> OP_HASH160 <E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308> OP_EQUAL
```

Screenshot:

[image: see screenshot]

My script fails even though both the hashes are same. Why?

Comment: why are you trying to calculate the hash160 of a Bitcoin address? That is not common. Also looks like the tool thinks the address is a hex value (0x prefix) which would obviously been invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they aren't the same. It appears that this script IDE interprets things inside of angle brackets (`<` and `>`) as strings, not as hex values. However a hash is not a string, it is a sequence of bytes which may be represented using hexadecimal values.

So what your script is actually doing is putting the string `1PUzZ61FSVTn12CafJC85Vy1ts3BoFcXdU` on the stack and then hashing it and putting the byte value `E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308`. But then you push the string `E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308` onto the stack except this has a byte value of `45313035453031423932313139434335354437353332343843453341333243383241394242333038`. The `OP_EQUAL` is then comparing the two byte values `E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308` and `45313035453031423932313139434335354437353332343843453341333243383241394242333038` which are obviously not equal to each other and thus the script fails.

Instead you need to tell this program that you want to push the byte values `E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308` to the stack, not the string representation of these hex characters. To do that, just don't surround it with angle brackets. This works for me:

```
<1PUzZ61FSVTn12CafJC85Vy1ts3BoFcXdU> OP_HASH160 E105E01B92119CC55D753248CE3A32C82A9BB308 OP_EQUAL
```